# Command to find Linux terminal of the process

Tags: linux

I have pid of a process on linux machine.I want to retrieve the terminal/console on which the standard output is getting displayed.

Comment: can you explain exactly what do you need ?

Comment: `ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/0`.

Comment: I am executing a command on my linux machine and it's printing the output on console.Now i have another terminal opened and I have the pid of the the process.I want to know if any command exists using which I can know on which terminal the output is getting printed.

Comment: Search parent process.. Use `ps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ps` command can do it.

```
ps -o tty -p $pid
```